# Change value in SharePoint list filter

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a SharePoint list filter webpart. How can I change the default value "Empty" in SharePoint without breaking hive folder.
[Default "Empty" option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsK7Z.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the default value for list filter web part, you can set this in web part "Advanced Filter Option":

[image]

Comment: I am not changing the default value. What I want is to change the "Empty" text

Comment: You can change the Empty text by modify the dom via Jquery.